# saving player name & score to text file and delete the lowest score

Tags: csv, xna, streamwriter

I want to add a save function to my game, where the program saving the score and the player name to the outer source like text file.

I already have the text file like this, and it already contain some dummy data :

```
AOLAS, 3500
SITI, 3600
JAMILAH, 2200
SURATNA, 3400
TATANG, 2000
```

what I want to do is, the program to save the player name & score to the text file. but before write the new data, it check the text file, line-per-line to get the line of data which has the lowest score on it and delete it. and after that the new data will be saved to the text file.

I tried to something like this :

```
   public void saveHighScores()
   {
        string line;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("highscore.txt");
        while ((line = sw.WriteLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            hiScoreName = parts[0].Trim();
            QuizScreen.score = Int32.Parse(parts[1].Trim());
        }

        sw.Close();
   }
```

actually I just reversed my read high score data function from before, because I think it'll work like that. but it doesn't.

it get the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'" in the WriteLine().

...and I still can't figured the logic(and it's code) how to check the lowest score, delete it, and then save the new data...

Comment: That code won't compile (I reformatted post so as to be more obvious)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are doing, you're trying to write a file the same way you would read it, is this what you need?

```
public void saveHighScores(string hiScoreName, int score)
{
    string line;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("highscore.txt");
    line = hiScoreName + ", " + score.ToString();
    sw.WriteLine(line);

    sw.Close();
}
```

You can also use arrays or lists if you need to record multiple high scores

Edit:

I think you need to understand the logic behind writing and reading from a file.

When you read a file, this line:

```
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
```

checks whether the next line is null, or that we've reached the end of the file.
When you write to a file, you can skip this part, as, most often, you don't want to stop when you reach the end of a file. ALso, sw.WriteLine() writes to the file but doesn't return a value, which is causing your error.

in my code above, the lines:

```
line = hiScoreName + ", " + score.ToString();
sw.WriteLine(line);
```

mean this:

```
line = hiScoreName followed by a comma followed by the score = "name, score"
write that line to the file
```